# Script to power off a pc too brutal?

Tags: linux, bash, debian

Based on this site: [Shutting down  Debian linux machine](http://debianhelp.co.uk/shutdown.htm), I wrote a script to power off a Debian computer. However, I feel it's too brutal, like the power was cut off by an accident or something. What I want is that the script would behave just like a human would normally power off. Is this the case or the script is forcing the computer to power off abnormally?

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo poweroff
```

Why am I worried? Because when I run the script, the computer powers off immediately, while where you are choosing power off from the GUI it takes some time to complete the process of powering off.

In other words the question is:

*Is it equivalent to pressing the power button of computer's power or is it quivalnet to selecting power off from the GUI environment?*

---

`/etc/init.d` shows a list of programs, like sudo, but powerpff is not listed there.

`/etc/rc.local` does this:

```
exit 0
```

is this better? Or maybe a combination of `exit` and `poweroff` would be better?

Comment: No it should shutdown normally, closing services as descibed in the `/etc/init.d` or `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: @JID edited with the contents. Are you sure it's ok? Because when I run the script the pc power offs immediately.

Comment: No, just poweroff is okay. When i said it closes services as described in `/etc/init.d` i meant it foillows the normal procedure for shutting down . In init.d there will be folders such as `rc3.d` for each run level. Inside each one is a list of symbolic links to tell the computer which order to shut down services in. I was simply saying that it will not abruptly stop anything and will safely close all open services(as much as it would if you press shutdown anyway)

Comment: If the machine is powering off immediately (which shouldn't be the case), try using `sudo shutdown -h now` instead. This tells the system to `halt` (`-h`) which will gracefully close services.

Comment: JID you mean if I press the power button of the computer's tower? If this is what the script does, then it's no good. @mplf I will try that later, because I am installing a library now. However, the same question goes for `shutdown` too, i.e. is it equivalent to pressing the power button of computer's power or is it quivalnet to selecting power off from the GUI environment?

Comment: @G.Samaras no i mean if you pressed shutdown in the startmenu or whatever. @mplf hopefully poweroff should pretty much just run shutdown . But yeah it probably is better to just run `shutdown -h` if you are unsure how poweroff has been set.

Comment: I see @JID. Thank you both! Pity you did not make an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`poweroff` is ok from my point of view. I usually switch off the computer like that. It will (as mentioned) end correctly the running services and syncs the disks. **It is not** at all like hardware unplug. If you have something running, instalation, updates... everything gets a kill signal and you loose your work. Same with GUI programs.

If you want to protect some running programs against poweroff, you must elaborate on the script.

`poweroff` and `halt` are the links to `reboot`.  `reboot` with `-f` reboots by itself, else (i.e. typically) it calls `shutdown` tool (see`man reboot`). This means that anyway, in most cases, you always end up with `shutdown` call.